# Where does intellij store external tool configurations on linux?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying to share some external tools I've defined in intellij with some other developers.  I've read that the configuration of each group is stored in an xml file, however I can't seem to find the location of these files on linux.

Does anyone know where they are stored by default?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking in Settings folder for tools subfolder

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

For example in macOS it is:
~/Library/Preferences//tools

Comment: How do you save and distribute this? When users open a project I want them to be imported automatically.